# Fatal error: Call to a member function num_rows() on boolean in Code igniter

Tags: codeigniter

I have face this Fatal error:  problem in local.

```
$rr = $this->CI->db->query("select * from $table $condition ");

$mm = $rr->num_rows();

if ($mm>0) {

    return 1;

} else {

    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 

$this->db->select("your stuff");
$query = $this->db->get("your table");

if($query->num_rows() > 0 ) {
     return 1;
}
else {
     return 0;
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->CI->db->query("select * from $table $condition ");
```

remove CI and

```
$this->db->query("select * from $table $condition ");
```

Answer (score 0):

First have you autoload the database

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database');
```

If a your trying to load a library then use the $CI instance http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/ancillary_classes.html#get-instance

***application > libraries > Example.php***

```
<?php

class Example {

   protected $CI;

   public function __construct() {
       $this->CI =& get_instance();
   }

   public function somename() {
       $query = $this->CI->db->query("select * from $table $condition ");

       if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {

       return 1; // return true;

       } else {

       return 0; // return false;

       }
   }

}
```

If on models

***application > models > Example_model.php***

```
<?php

class Example_model extends CI_Model {

   public function __construct() {
     parent::__construct();
   }

   public function somename() {
       $query = $this->db->query("select * from $table $condition ");

       if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {

       return 1; // return true;

       } else {

       return 0; // return false;

       }
   }

}
```

Comment: In your library example, $this->CI needs a property to live in, i.e. protected $CI; or the like...

Answer (score 0):

Update one CI core file and resolve your error:

Go to : **System/database/** and edit **DB_active_rec.php** file 
Go to line no 990 and see blow code

```
if ($query->num_rows() == 0)
{
    return 0;
}
```

**Update to**

```
if (!$query || $query->num_rows() == 0)
{
    return 0;
}
```

Hope resolved your `num_rows()` issue.

Answer (score 0):

class Site_m extends MY_Model {

```
protected $_table_name = 'setting';
protected $_primary_key = 'option';
protected $_primary_filter = 'intval';
protected $_order_by = "option asc";

function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
}

function get_site($id) {
    $compress = array();
    $query = $this->db->get('setting');
    foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
        $compress[$row->fieldoption] = $row->value;//here I am getting error
    }
    return (object) $compress;
}
```

}

/* End of file site_m.php */

Comment: Don't just blurt out code. Adding some text to explain how this best answers the question will improve the long-term value of the answer and prevent it from being deleted during review.

Answer (score 0):

This is fix in core CI-2
File
\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line in code
https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/database/DB_driver.php#L659

replace FALSE before end code

```
    // Run the Query
    if (FALSE === ($this->result_id = $this->simple_query($sql)))
    {
        if ($this->save_queries == TRUE)
        {
            $this->query_times[] = 0;
        }

        // This will trigger a rollback if transactions are being used
        $this->_trans_status = FALSE;

        if ($this->db_debug)
        {
            // grab the error number and message now, as we might run some
            // additional queries before displaying the error
            $error_no = $this->_error_number();
            $error_msg = $this->_error_message();

            // We call this function in order to roll-back queries
            // if transactions are enabled.  If we don't call this here
            // the error message will trigger an exit, causing the
            // transactions to remain in limbo.
            $this->trans_complete();

            // Log and display errors
            log_message('error', 'Query error: '.$error_msg);
            return $this->display_error(
                                    array(
                                            'Error Number: '.$error_no,
                                            $error_msg,
                                            $sql
                                        )
                                    );
        }

        return FALSE;
    }
```

To

```
// Run the Query
    if (FALSE === ($this->result_id = $this->simple_query($sql)))
    {
        if ($this->save_queries == TRUE)
        {
            $this->query_times[] = 0;
        }

        // This will trigger a rollback if transactions are being used
        $this->_trans_status = FALSE;

        if ($this->db_debug)
        {
            // grab the error number and message now, as we might run some
            // additional queries before displaying the error
            $error_no = $this->_error_number();
            $error_msg = $this->_error_message();

            // We call this function in order to roll-back queries
            // if transactions are enabled.  If we don't call this here
            // the error message will trigger an exit, causing the
            // transactions to remain in limbo.
            $this->trans_complete();

            // Log and display errors
            log_message('error', 'Query error: '.$error_msg);
            return $this->display_error(
                                    array(
                                            'Error Number: '.$error_no,
                                            $error_msg,
                                            $sql
                                        )
                                    );
        }

        $CR = new CI_DB_result();
        return  $CR;
    }
```

Default should be return object empty

```
 $CR = new CI_DB_result();
return  $CR;
```